# Using module in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to learn my way around JavaScript better. To do that, I thought I would try my hand at writing a reusable component. I want to be able to test this component. Currently, I have the following file structure:

```
/lib
 /services
  /my-service
    my-service.js
    my-service-tests.js
```

`my-service.js` looks like the following:

```
function MyService() {
}

MyService.prototype.serviceType = "Test";

MyService.prototype.execute = function(p1, p2) {
  console.log('executing with ' + p1 + ' and ' + p2);
  try {
    // do stuff
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
};
```

`my-service-tests.js` uses Jasmine and looks like the following:

```
describe("MyService", function() {
  it(" Can execute", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I can successfully execute the test from the command-line via Gulp. However, my challenge is, I want to call the execute function on MyService. Ultimately, I want to write tests around MyService. I was hoping to do something like this in the test above:

```
var service = new MyService();
service.execute();
```

Is there a way to do this? I feel like I'm very close. Unfortunately, there seems to be something that I'm not fully understanding. If I just add this code, I get a reference error. Its like it doesn't know where MyService is located. I'm not sure what to do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: To me, it looks good. I work with code similar to this.  What browser (IE has issues with `console.log`)? And, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you actually load `my-service.js` in the test?

Comment: @plalx `my-service.js` is not loaded in the test. I do not know how to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was forgetting:

```
module.exports = MyService;
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your execute needs a p1 and p2.

**UPDATE**:

Tried ...

```
var service = new MyService();
service.execute();
service.execute(1, "2");
```

Ran the code as defined here ... **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/6Ln04vro/)** and it works fine in both examples.

I would be looking at your load order for the JS files.

Comment: No, they will just be `undefined` if nothing is passed.

Comment: Looks like something didn't get loaded.